# in Vue PUT POST DELETE method showing not allowed when middlewear included

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to implepement vue in my laravel application. Simple CRUD. The fetching and showing of data is working fine, but edit, delete, add is not. It is working if there is no auth checking middlewear in feedController. Need to make it work while the middlewear included.

Here is my add method:

```
fetch('api/feed', {
                method: 'post',
                body: JSON.stringify(this.feed),
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then( data=> {
                this.feed.title = '';
                this.feed.body = '';
                alert('Feed Added');
                this.fetchFeeds();
            })
```

Here is my delete method:

```
 deleteFeed(id){
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')){
            fetch(`api/feed/${id}`, {
                method: 'delete'
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data=> {
                alert('Article Removed');
                this.fetchFeeds();
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
    }
```

Here are the routes in api.php

```
/Create new feed
Route::post('feed', 'FeedController@store');
//Update feed
Route::put('feed', 'FeedController@store');
//Delete feed
Route::delete('feed/{id}', 'FeedController@destroy');
```

And finally here is the controller's functions where the middlewear is.
For adding:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $feed = $request->isMethod('put')?Feeds::findOrFail($request->feed_id):new Feeds;

        $feed->id= $request->input('feed_id');
        $feed->title= $request->input('title');
        $feed->body= $request->input('body');
        // $feed->image= "Test Image String";
        // $feed->link="Test Link String";
        // $feed->user_id=4;

        if($feed->save())
        {
            return new FeedResource($feed);
        }

    }
```

For deleting:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $feed = Feeds::findOrFail($id);
        if ($feed->delete()){
            return new FeedResource($feed);
        }


    }
```

Comment: Check if route exists in routes list. If not clear cache.  arisan route:list artisan route:cache

Comment: They are there.